# Count if multiple conditions met in varlist

Tags: if-statement, foreach, count, stata

I am trying to count values of many string variables (`hh_1_age hh_2_age hh_3_age` etc.) based on multiple conditions, and send output to a new variable `schoolage`.

The closest I think I've gotten is coded below...but I'm still getting error messages. I'm hoping I'm on the right track and it's just a small syntax error:

```
generate schoolage = .

foreach var of varlist hh_* {
    count if `v'=="6 - 10 years of age" | `v'=="11 - 14 years of age"
}
```

Comment: You don't say what error message you got.

Comment: Sorry about that. Error message: =="6 - 10 years of age" invalid name
r(198);

Comment: Thanks for adding an error message. I don't see why you get that error if the code in my answer works....

Comment: Sorry. I meant I got that error code originally with my code - your code worked perfectly.

Comment: I see the error -- belatedly. You set up the loop in terms of local macro `var` but refer to `v` inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a great deal of guesswork compared with the small amount of information given. Please note the suggestions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/how-to-create-high-quality-reproducible-examples-in-stata) for good Stata questions, which include giving a reproducible example based on real(istic) data.

You may have data on individual members of a household and wish to count how many are of school age, that meaning aged between 6 and 14 years.

```
gen schoolage = 0 

foreach v of var hh_*_age { 
    replace schoolage = schoolage + inlist(`v', "6 - 10 years of age", "11 - 14 years of age") 
}
```

would be one solution to that.

Note that this assumes that the variables in question really are string, as you report. Further, checks for equality are entirely literal: all characters must match in turn.

For most purposes holding data on each individual in a separate observation is a much better practice than your question seems to imply.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Will look up the inlist function as I've never seen that.

Comment: https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0026 explains about `inlist()` and its sibling `inrange()`. Puzzling out what `if inlist(1, x, y, z)` does is instructive.

Comment: @MJPhillips Please also read [How to create high quality reproducible examples in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/) for tips on how to improve your future questions.